# Efficiently remove strings that are contained within other strings in a column in R

Tags: r, string, search, substring

Suppose I have a data frame like the one below:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c("11_22", "11_22_bb", "11_22_bb_33", 
                      "22_bb_33", "bb_33", "ab_cc_sd", "dd_e3_bb", 
                      "33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data

#                    id
#1                11_22
#2             11_22_bb
#3          11_22_bb_33
#4             22_bb_33
#5                bb_33
#6             ab_cc_sd
#7             dd_e3_bb
#8 33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc
```

The strings in rows 1-2 & 4-5 are contained in the string in row 3. **My goal is to remove rows 1-2 and rows 4-5 and retain only strings in rows that are not contained within other strings.**

**(1) The simplest solution** is comparing each row against all other rows, and flagging it if it is found to be contained in another one(s). For example:

```
data$flag <- TRUE
for( i in 1:nrow( data ) ){
  if( sum(grepl( data[i, 1], data[-i,1] )) > 0 )
      data$flag[ i ] <- FALSE
}
data <- data[data$flag, ]

#                    id flag
#3          11_22_bb_33 TRUE
#6             ab_cc_sd TRUE
#7             dd_e3_bb TRUE
#8 33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc TRUE
```

But this is not efficient, especially when dealing with longer data frames.

**(2) An improved solution seems** to be to:

1. Sort the strings in descending length order;
2. Compare each string (that is not the longest) to strings that are longer.
3. If a string is found to be contained within a longer string, this shorter string is flagged and will not be compared against when an even shorter string is being compared. (E.g., when `11_22_bb` is found to be contained within `11_22_bb_33`, `11_22_bb` is flagged, and when `11_22` is being compared, it will only be compared to `11_22_bb_33` and not `11_22_bb`.)

As shown below:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c("11_22", "11_22_bb", "11_22_bb_33", 
                       "22_bb_33", "bb_33", "ab_cc_sd", "dd_e3_bb", 
                       "33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$len_char <- nchar(data$id)
data <- data[ order(data$len_char, decreasing=TRUE),]
data$flag <- TRUE

for( i in 2:nrow(data)){
    if( sum(grepl( data[i, "id"],
        data[ data$len_char > data$len_char[i] & data$flag, "id"])) > 0
       )
        data[i, "flag"] <- FALSE
}
data <- data[data$flag, ]
data

#                    id len_char flag
#8 33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc       20 TRUE
#3          11_22_bb_33       11 TRUE
#6             ab_cc_sd        8 TRUE
#7             dd_e3_bb        8 TRUE
```

**My question**: is there a way to make this even more efficient. At this point the 2nd method takes about 16 seconds to reduce a 6700 row data frame (the final, resulting data frame is 1400 rows). The first method takes about 50 seconds.

Comment: try replacing `sum` with `any`?  Might gain you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it!

Comment: for that matter, replace the whole `if`  with `data[i, "flag"] <- any(grepl(data[i, "id"], data[ data$len_char > data$len_char[i] & data$flag, "id"]))`

Comment: @Benjamin: Your first suggestion seems to provide a 3 second speed up. I will try the 2nd one in a bit

Comment: The 2nd one makes the code cleaner, but doesn't seem to improve the speed.

Comment: I think my second one also gives you the reverse flag.  You might want `!any(.....`  But I'm getting kind of dizzy in my logicals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And `vapply` wins the day.

```
data<-data.frame(id=c("11_22", "11_22_bb", "11_22_bb_33", 
                       "22_bb_33", "bb_33", "ab_cc_sd", "dd_e3_bb", 
                       "33_34_sd_22_32_87_cc"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$len_char <- nchar(data$id)
data <- data[ order(data$len_char, decreasing=TRUE),]
data$flag <- TRUE

samp <- sample(1:nrow(data), 6700, replace = TRUE)

Strings <- Strings_orig <- data[samp, , drop=FALSE]

system.time({
  for( i in 2:nrow(Strings)){
    if( sum(grepl( Strings[i, "id"],
        Strings[ Strings$len_char > Strings$len_char[i] & Strings$flag, "id"])) > 0
       )
        Strings[i, "flag"] <- FALSE
}
})

 user  system elapsed  
 3.81    0.00    3.81 


Strings <- Strings_orig

system.time({
for (i in 2:nrow(Strings)){
  Strings$flag[i] <- !any(grepl( Strings[i, "id"],
        Strings[ Strings$len_char > Strings$len_char[i] & Strings$flag, "id"]))
}
})

  user  system elapsed 
  3.79    0.00    3.79 



Strings <- Strings_orig
fn <- function(id, len_char){
  any(grepl(id, Strings$id[Strings$len_char > len_char & Strings$flag]))
}
system.time({
  vapply(Strings$flag, fn, TRUE, len_char = Strings$len_char)
})
  user  system elapsed 
  1.03    0.00    1.03
```